# My cursor changes color and size when I click

Tags: display, lightdm, cursor, 4k-monitor

I have a 4k display attached to my laptop's builtin 1920x1080 display.

I have to use LightDM because my external monitor was not working with GDM.

When I don't click on anything my cursor is large and white in color like this:

[image: screenshot showing large white mouse pointer over desktop background]

When I click it gets smaller and turns black like this:

[image: screenshot showing smaller black mouse pointer over desktop background]

This happens regardless of the screen I am using at the time.

Is there a way to get the cursor to not change size and color?